# Controls bound to command not updating state

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've been using Commands for quite a while now. It's a good way of UI-to-Code interaction that fits perfectly into the WPF ecosystem and makes thing a lot easier (automatically disabling controls if the command can't be executed).

But I realize more and more often that commands simply don't work as expected. I'm not sure if I use them wrong but randomly some controls don't update their state. I have to click or use any UI element in order to make it update. This even confuses me as developer, so it's a no-go for any enduser. It destroys the workflow.

I'm using default UIRoutedCommands bound to my application window. I guess it doesn't require code here - it's done like in every tutorial.

What can I do about this issue? Is there a better alternative for it? I've heared that Expression behaviours are better but are they good to use, I mean it's obviously not part of the WPF framework itself?

**EDIT:** As requested some code for you guys.
This is the CanExecute of one element that doesn't get updated at a certain point. Implemented (I guess) like it should be.

```
public void CanExecuteAnalysis(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = Prefs.Instance.Project?.Assemblies?.Count > 0 &&
                    Prefs.Instance.Context.State == InjectionState.PreAnalyzed;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The CommandBinding, added to the bindings of my main window:

```
 <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static internal:CommandLibrary.StartAnalysis}" CanExecute="CanExecuteAnalysis" Executed="ExecuteAnalysis" />
```

The menu-bar item that subscribes to it:

```
<MenuItem Header="Start Analysis" Command="{x:Static internal:CommandLibrary.StartAnalysis}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
         <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="Data/analyze.png" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

And the thing that is actually not working is a custom styled menu (just a StackPanel with some buttons). Those buttons are the menu-items I've been talking. They got a disabled style (grayed out) when `IsEnabled == false`. Now when I click the item the analysis starts and when it finishes it normally would be disabled since `InjectionState == InjectionState.Analyzed` instead of *PreAnalyzed*. It does get disabled though first when I click some other element, it itself or do some other thing that triggers the `CommandManager` to invoke `RequerySuggested`.

Comment: Can we see code/xaml? What exactly are you trying to change with the commands that isn't working? the disabling of ui elements? What you're saying is it works but only on user interaction?

Comment: I do check for certain points. Like `Project != null` or `App.State == AppState.Analyzed`. It's basically a menu which you go through from the top to the bottom. It leads you visually through the process. Some points get disabled at certain points. But sometimes they do stay enabled until I click any UI element. Then it gets disabled since it invokes the `CanExecute()`. It does not always do that when necessary, so some changes don't apply until any UIElement was interacted with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some occasions command's CanExecute result changes and there is no way the command could know it. Look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(v=VS.110).aspx)

> **CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested** method.
>
> The CommandManager only pays attention to certain conditions in determining when the command target has changed, such as change in keyboard focus. In situations where the CommandManager does not sufficiently determine a change in conditions that cause a command to not be able to execute, InvalidateRequerySuggested can be called to force the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event.

Comment: I tried that. I implemented a timer which does invoke that method every 250ms in order to ensure that everything works fine (got only a handful of comments so I guess this doesn't produce too much CPU overhead - moreover it was a test). But it didn't change anything. Like these commands have never subscribed to the RequerySuggested-event.

Comment: @SharpShade you have to be more specific then. Smoking commands every day and everything's fine.

Comment: I have been using the approach that you and Viktor are discussing here (using a timer to call InvalidateRequerySuggested), and it has been working fine in all of my projects.  Can you post your code, just in case?

Comment: Added code and detailed explanation. Hope you get what I mean now :) I would expect using the timer should actually get it working, but it still doesn't change it's disabled state until I trigger the `CommandManager` myself by interacting with the UI.

Comment: Okay @Dave you were right about it. It does work and I just found out why it wasn't working for me. I've been using the `System.Threading.Timer` which of course does a callback which happens on a non-UI-thread. After calling `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested, DispatcherPriority.Normal);` it did work finally.